# Сетевые настройки Windows 10

Tags: windows

Здравствуйте.

Две "зеркальные" рабочие станции HP (одинаковое железо).

На обоих установлена Windows 10 OEM лицензия.

Необходимо перенести сетевые настройки карты  с одной станции на другую.

(Сетевые настройки: IP,DNS,DHCP, Буферы приема, Буферы передачи, Большой кадр, Контрольная сумма разгрузки IPv4, Скорость и дуплекс, Сетевой адрес, управление потоком и все остальные сетевые настройки.)

Вопросы:

1) Как перенести сетевые настройки через реестр? (экспорт какой ветки реестра надо сделать)

2) Есть ли другие инструнструменты для переноса сетевых настроек?

Answer (score 2):

1. Найти по имени интерфейс в HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
2. Найти по CLSID его сетевые настройки в HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services и экспортировать в файл
3. Найти по PnPInstanceId сетевую карту в HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318} и экспортировать её настройки в файл
4. Посмотреть то же на второй станции, поправить значения и импортировать файлы.

Но не убеждён, что это всё, что нужно...

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ буду пробывать.